# Python class interface design

Tags: python

Is there a way to easily expose the APi of an internal object of a python class without retyping every API of that object? For example, I write a redis replica class and all my functions are like

```
def get_connection(self, name):
    ........
    host, conn = self.colo_rings[name]
    return conn

def hgetall(self, name):
    return self.get_connection(name).hgetall(name)

def hset(self, name, key, value):
    return self.get_connection(name).hset(name, key, value)

def hsetnx(self, name, key, value):
    return self.get_connection(name).hsetnx(name, key, value)

def hdel(self, name, *key, colo=None):
    return self.get_connection(name).hdel(name, *key)
```

How can I improve this code and make it not that "ugly"?

Comment: Is `self.get_connection(key)` correct in the call to `hgetall`?

Comment: Inheritance comes to mind.

Comment: Is your example accurate? 1) In `hgetall` you use `key` to look up your, but in `hset`, you use `name`? 2) In `hset`, you invoke `get_connection.set` instead of `get_connection.hset`.

Comment: It seems like you want to mask a pool of objects that are referenced by name. Instead, you could just implement the pool part as a class. Suppose this object is called connections and calls are `connections.hgetall('aname', 'akey')`. You'd have an object called connections and its calls are `connections['aname'].hgetall('akey')`.

Comment: @HuCao - could you please fix your example as per Rob's request? Your parameters and method names aren't consistent and so we can't figure out what to do.

Comment: @tdelaney - Fixed the code to make it more understandable. The redis connections are stored in a consistent hash ring actually. The details are omitted in getConnections.

Comment: @HuCao - could you update hset target to be name, key, value. The answer you accepted only works if the delegate call signature matches. The mismatch in your example may be puzzling to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use something similar to this:

```
class B(object):
  def __getattribute__(self, method):
    try:
      return getattr(self, method)
    except:
      return getattr(self.get_connection(key), method)
```

The advantage here is that you can still use methods that don't exist on your connection by defining them on the class, but anything that you don't define and that exists on the connection will be used when you try to access it via `myB.hgetall()` (for example).

For completeness - `__getattr__` is sufficient:

```
class B(object):
  def __getattr__(self, method):
    return getattr(self.get_connection(key), method)
```

Comment: I think `__getattr__` is the better fit here. It is called only if regular attribute lookup fails, so the try/except isnt needed.

Comment: OP's example is very poorly presented, but I think that the delegated methods take a different number of parameters (the name is stripped) so simply forwarding the call doesn't work.

Comment: @tdelaney - I wasn't quite certain either, based on Rob's comment.  Either this or `__getattr__` should get where the OP needs if he's actually just forwarding, and if not, the question needs some revision to clarify.

Comment: I got g.d.d.c's idea and did some research. @tdelaney : yes, __getattr__ is better.

Comment: I mean: `__getattr__`. Sorry I am newbie of the markdown format